# fractional part of a extended number

Tags: delphi

For get fractional part in a number i have problem.

I tried with this way:

```
var
  x: Extended;
begin
  x := 1.563;
  x := Frac(x);
  ShowMessage(FormatFloat('#.000', x));
end;
```

It will give result `.563` but i dont need `.` (dot)  in the result.

Actually, the issues for separate fractional of number is a dot in the result.

How i get just `563` in that example ? Is there other way for do that ?

Thanks ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A trivial solution is to strip off the decimal separator:

```
Copy(FormatFloat('#.000', x), 2, MaxInt);
```